# How to fix GET https://app/node_modules/firebase/compat/app net::ERR_ABORTED 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, http-status-code-404

i'm currently trying to create a website using firebase realtime database.
I'm new to this so i don't really understand what is wrong.

I've managed to get information from my firebase database if i run the index.js script

```
Object {nom: "Mister", prenom: "Someone"}
```

However, when doing firebase deploy, i get this error on the html page :

```
index.js:4 GET https://<app-name>/node_modules/firebase/compat/app net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Here are my folders:

[Folder Organisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqbpK.png)

My html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="src/style.css">

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <!--
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
        <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.1.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>


      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body { background: #ECEFF1; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #message { background: white; max-width: 360px; margin: 100px auto 16px; padding: 32px 24px; border-radius: 3px; }
      #message h2 { color: #ffa100; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 8px; }
      #message h1 { font-size: 22px; font-weight: 300; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin: 0 0 16px;}
      #message p { line-height: 140%; margin: 16px 0 24px; font-size: 14px; }
      #message a { display: block; text-align: center; background: #039be5; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: white; padding: 16px; border-radius: 4px; }
      #message, #message a { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); }
      #load { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); text-align: center; font-size: 13px; }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body, #message { margin-top: 0; background: white; box-shadow: none; }
        body { border-top: 16px solid #ffa100; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>
    <button id="submitPost" type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.firestore().doc('/foo/bar').get().then(() => { });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            'auth', 
            'database', 
            'firestore',
            'functions',
            'messaging', 
            'storage', 
            'analytics', 
            'remoteConfig',
            'performance',
          ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          console.log("database!!")
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="src/index.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My index.js:

```
console.log("himmm");
//../../node_modules/

import firebase from "../../node_modules/firebase/compat/app";
import "../../node_modules/firebase/compat/database";
//import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/firebase-database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//document.getElementById("submitPost").addEventListener("click", test)

function test(){
    console.log("Test");
}

function readUserData(){
    const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
    dbRef.child("users").child("0").get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        } else {
            console.log("No data available");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
readUserData()
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mainproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node public/src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Someone :)",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": "Web app",
  "exports": {
    "./analytics": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./analytics/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./analytics/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./analytics/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./app": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./app/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./app/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./app/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./app-check": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./app-check/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./app-check/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./app-check/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./auth": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./auth/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./auth/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./auth/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./auth/cordova": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./auth/cordova/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./auth/cordova/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./auth/cordova/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./auth/react-native": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./auth/react-native/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./auth/react-native/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./auth/react-native/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./database": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./database/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./database/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./database/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./firestore": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./firestore/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./firestore/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./firestore/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./firestore/lite": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./firestore/lite/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./firestore/lite/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./firestore/lite/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./functions": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./functions/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./functions/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./functions/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./messaging": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./messaging/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./messaging/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./messaging/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./messaging/sw": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./messaging/sw/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./messaging/sw/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./messaging/sw/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./performance": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./performance/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./performance/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./performance/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./remote-config": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./remote-config/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./remote-config/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./remote-config/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./storage": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./storage/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./storage/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./storage/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/analytics": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/analytics/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/analytics/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/app": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/app/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/app/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/app/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/app-check": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/app-check/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/app-check/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/app-check/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/auth": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/auth/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/auth/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/auth/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/database": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/database/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/database/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/database/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/firestore": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/firestore/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/firestore/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/functions": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/functions/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/functions/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/functions/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/messaging": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/messaging/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/messaging/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/messaging/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/performance": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/performance/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/performance/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/performance/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/remote-config": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/remote-config/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/remote-config/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/remote-config/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "./compat/storage": {
      "node": {
        "require": "./compat/storage/dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./compat/storage/dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./compat/storage/dist/index.esm.js"
    }
  },
  "./package.json": "./package.json"
}
```

Also, when importing like this :

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
```

I have this error on html page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/compat/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

So i have to write:

```
import firebase from "../../node_modules/firebase/compat/app"
```

if someone can help please.